# Overriding alpha and size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plotting function:

```
drawFoo <- function(df) {
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=c)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=1, size=5)
}
bar <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, c=as.factor(rbinom(10, 1, 0.5)))
drawFoo(bar)
```

Now I'd like to use its return with slight adjustments. Say, to change colours I use

```
drawFoo(bar) + scale_colour_manual(values = 1:2)
```

However, when using the same approach to size and alpha, none of these work:

```
drawFoo(bar) + scale_size_manual(values = 1:10)
drawFoo(bar) + scale_alpha_manual(values = rep(1/10, 10))
```

and I always have the first picture unaffected.
As far as I can tell, that happens when the aesthetic in question is not mapped to a variable. But I have no idea why this is an expected behaviour, so any explanations and overriding workarounds are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can add size and alpha as arguments like this:

```
drawFoo <- function(df,alpha=1,size=5) {
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=c)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=alpha, size=size)
}
```

So you have 1 and 5 as default values, but can change them while using your function.

```
drawFoo(df) ## alpha=1, size=5
drawFoo(df,alpha=0.5,size=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your function you set alpha and the size, so it is not an aesthetics. A with a aesthetic you map a visual element like size or transparency to a variable - and with a scale you describe HOW you map it (for example low levels of the variable to green and high levels to red).

If you set a visual element to some quality, for example, you set the pointsize to 5, then a scale makes no sense anymore (because there is no mapping anymore which you can decribe by a scale - you simply SET ALL points to have the size 5), because your pointsize is directly set to five without any relation to a variable.

It does not depend on the function you have written, you can directly use the latter two scales on the ggplot object you use inside the function - there will be no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How do I override these "static" size and alpha from my example then? It's still unclear to me if that is possible.